# How to create typescript interface for array of objects with array as values

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have input data in this form:

```
const input = {
    postcode: ['0000']
    submitted: ['yes']
}

const output = {
    postcode: '0000'
    submitted: 'yes'
}
```

How to create interface for input data?

I tried:

```
interface inputData {
    postcode: string[]
    submitted: string[]
}

interface outputData {
    postcode: string
    submitted: string
}
```

But I get error while applying it:

```
const extract = (input: inputData[]): outputData => {
  for (const key in input) {
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(input, key)) {
      input[key] = input[key][0]; // Error here
    }
  }
  const output: any = input;
  return output;
}
```

Error: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'inputData'. Property '0' does not exist on type 'inputData'.`

Comment: `:outputData` isnt a type (its a variable) What are you expecting the output to look like?

Comment: its still not clear, in your first paragraph you say you have input data in the form... and you define a const called `outputData`. and your output doesnt have the type of `outputData`. Did you mean `const output = {
    postcode: '0000'
    submitted: 'yes'
} ?

Comment: Looks like your input and output data structure looks same,  so you can create one interface and use that interface for input and output both.

Comment: @DamianGreen My bad. updated the question again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an interface with an indexer:

```
interface EnumServiceGetOrderBy {
    [index: number]: { id: number; label: string; key: any };
}
```

Comment: How is this the right approach? What's `EnumServiceGetOrderBy`. where are `id`, `label` and `key` mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version

```
function hasOwnProperty<X extends {}, Y extends PropertyKey>
  (obj: X, prop: Y): obj is X & Record<Y, unknown> {
  return obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)
}

interface inputData {
    postcode: string[];
    submitted: string[];
}
type outputData = inputData;

const extract = (input: inputData): outputData => {
    for (const key in input) {
        if (hasOwnProperty(input, key)) {
            const value = input[key];

            if (value instanceof Array) {
                input[key] = value[0];
            }
        }
    }
    const output: any = input;
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the information you've provided the type of `inputData` is Record<string,string[]>`
Record is a utility  type ([Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html))

```
    postcode: ['0000'],
    submitted: ['yes']
}

type inputDataT = Record<string,string[]>

interface inputData {
    postcode: string[]
    submitted: string[]
}

const extract = (input: inputDataT) => {
  const output: any = input;
  for (const key in input) {
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(input, key)) {
      output[key] = input[key][0];
    }
  }

  return output;
}
console.log(extract(inputData))
```

Also if you're sure that there will only ever be one string in the property value array you can make it stronger as follows:

```
type inputDataT = Record<string,[string]>
const inputData:inputDataT = {
    postcode: ['0000'],
    submitted: ['yes']
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmADgVygEQIZQzAvDAbwCgZSZERpQATAUwC4YBtAcgAYO2WBdAGhLIRkAIwC2cKFFrVGrAJ60IPIgF8iRKHMS14SVJmwAVPDABKtUACdqAHmiWEAc172nTbgD51CKZYBmGMA6CCjoWDjEZOSUUDQMMK5gju4CpEJiElIyCVAOSSlqRKCQsLQAHrmBsPgAFCGojPVhRgCUeB6EAsXQMCCooYwYYHImTQDcAn4gljA13bAA1rQjCLqhbZFkcH6zAPLCAFYWUAB0ABYYELsA7mAACpYg2paaJ8AYADYfdXpQvDBLOQtDapMh9KChJiA7ijX5Q5bcJhsbgTKJqUiFUiWWhQZCWMC9fqoCZqbogD60E4fECOGrlSrAKA-UIGDDAoA)

Comment: Can you please tell what is `Record`?

Comment: I can actually only use this `type inputDataT = Record<string,string[]>` and it still works but looking at interface, it doesn't represent what are the types inside the record..

Comment: it matches the type in your question, please update the question with actual data if it differs

Comment: Yes but what if someone pass the input as `postcodeBlahBlah: ['0000']`, will it still validate? it has be only `postcode: ['0000']` right?

Comment: I've posted 2 different ways of validating against your data. Without knowing the exact schema it's not possibel to know the exact format.